# How to display children of "publish-composite collection" on Template View

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Considering the example given at https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite

How to display nested children on the template view. I mean, displaying ***top 2 comments on the post*** on the view.

I have searched a lot over internet for this children tree display on Template View, didn't find any.

**Code**

```
publishComposite('topTenPosts', {
    find() {
        // Find top ten highest scoring posts
        return Posts.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 10 });
    },
    children: [
        {
            find(post) {
                // Find post author. Even though we only want to return
                // one record here, we use "find" instead of "findOne"
                // since this function should return a cursor.
                return Meteor.users.find(
                    { _id: post.authorId },
                    { fields: { profile: 1 } });
            }
        },
        {
            find(post) {
                // Find top two comments on post
                return Comments.find(
                    { postId: post._id },
                    { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 2 });
            },
            children: [
                {
                    find(comment, post) {
                        // Find user that authored comment.
                        return Meteor.users.find(
                            { _id: comment.authorId },
                            { fields: { profile: 1 } });
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: There is no actual tree in your client-side database. Each document goes to its corresponding collection. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Blaze it should just be a simple set of templates where you search for the related comments and authors in a helper, displaying the posts and comments with nested `{{#each}}` loops.

html:

```
<template name="posts">
{{#each posts}}
  Title: {{title}} posted on: {{date}} by: {{authorName}}
  {{#each comments}}
    {{> comment}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="comment">
Post comment {{body}} by {{authorName}} on {{createdAt}}
</template>
```

Now for the helpers:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  posts(){
    return Posts.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 10 });
  },
  comments(){
    return Comments.find({ postId: this._id },{ sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 2 });
  },
  authorName(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.authorId).username;
});

Template.comment.helpers({
  authorName(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.authorId).username;
  },
});
```

Note the use of `this` in these helpers. `this` will be the value of the data *context* at the point of evaluation. Inside the `{{#each}}` blocks `this` takes on the value of the current document, i.e. an object with keys.

You can keep the `authorName` helpers DRY by creating a *global helper* if you like.

Comment: How are you? if we make subscriptions and helpers right away inside the templates, then what is the need for `publish-composite` package? making nested children? I have not understood the purpose behind the same. My code still will work without `publish-composite` package, right, with your above code?

Comment: Publish-composite helps you ensure you publish exactly what is needed and no more. There are several ways to publish your nested data here.